# Error while using controller to read text file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got error when using controller to read text file:

```
#my_page.html.erb
<input id="test_input" >

#controller.rb
def my_page
 File.open($directory+'\test.TXT', 'r') do |f1|  
    $line = f1.readlines
    f1.close    
 end    
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
 end
end

#my_page.js.erb
el = document.getElementById(test_input); 
el.innerHTML='<%=$line$>';
```

It load blank page without input and I don't know why, Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file??

Comment: Please mention the error also..

Comment: And, your code looks like PHP code copied and pasted into Ruby code...

Comment: In my view, it have a input <input id="test_input" > .I am trying to read a text file and show it's content in input but it load blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are doing. Here is what you can do.

```
#controller.rb
def my_page
  @text= File.open('your_file.txt').read
end

#my_page.html.erb
<input id="test_input" value="<%= @text %>" />
```

When you refresh your page, the text should show up on your page. No need to use Javascript now. You should use it when you are requesting the resource using AJAX.

If you would like to update the value of the text box, you need to add a new action in your controller and update your routes.rb accordingly. Also, it's always a good idea to use form helpers that Rails provide to utilize security feature (CSFR token), as shown below. If you have a model for the text field, you can use a form_for helper. You can read about them in

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Here is the code, nonetheless.

```
#my_page.html.erb

<%= form_tag save_text_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :test_input, @text %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>

# in your controller
def save_text
  updated_text = params[:test_input]
  # do something with the text
end

# in your routes.rb
post "save_text" => "your_controller_name#save_text", as: "save_text"
```

Comment: What should I do If I want to create a button to update value in text whenever I change content of txt file?

<input id="test_input" value="<%= text %>" />
<button>id="test_button" onclick="#function to update text" </button>

Comment: Tks, maybe I should go back to basics .

Comment: Learning Rails takes time and effort. I think you are doing great! I hope you enjoy Rails! It's really an awesome tool.

Comment: I have one more question, I did like you said and it update text in localhost:3000/save_text. What should I do if I want update text in same page when I click on submit button?